# Reacts Class Components or Hooks

Tags: reactjs

Basically I am learning react and along the way following a teaching course. The instructor taught us basics and then moved onto hooks. Not focusing much onto class components.

whether someone should move with hooks or go and get better at class components. Do hooks cover all aspects of the class components in order to build upon larger projects or there are still some aspects where we have to use hooks.

Comment: Here's a [motivation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html#motivation) on why React reacted hooks.

Comment: Yeah this was refreshing for me. Thanks. I don't need to look back to classes any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ask that - is there any difference between classes and React functions? Of course, there are: **it's in the mental model !**

After introducing React hooks, it seems that React teams wants developers to use functional components whenever possible (which better follows JavaScript's functional nature). Of course there's motivation behind this and they are:

- It’s really hard to re-use stateful logic between components
- Complex components become hard to understand
- Classes confuse both people and machines

Functional component with hooks can do almost everything in compare to a class component.

You can go with functional component if your component doesn't do much more than take in some props and render. You can think of these as pure functions because they will always render and behave the same, given the same props. Also, they don't care about lifecycle methods or have their own internal state.

But there will bee some scenarios where you'll need to use a regular React class:

- Component needs to maintain state
- Component is re-rendering too much and you need to control that via
  shouldComponentUpdate but you can also do this in Function component using
  useEffect now
- You need a container component

Hope all these make sense to you !

Comment: So, can we add full functionality with react hooks without using components like using useEffect and other hooks?

Comment: not clear about your question properly ! please elaborate more. But yeah you can achieve almost everything by functional component.

Answer (score 0):

Here we go,

About class components => the is useful for maintaining code, most of the problems of class components are about how to deal with reusability, hooks solve most of them.

About hooks => this is the real deal, hooks allow you to create really reusable components,
class components are really hard to reuse some state logic, Higher-order components (HOC) tends to become a monster really hard to read, lifting up the state is another pain in the ass, hooks helps you with all that.